# How do I add 0 rows under certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` of the form

df=

```
  index   ID     A       B
    
    0      a     0       111
    1      a     1       111
    2      a     2       111
    3      b     3       111
    4      c     0       111
    5      c     2       111
    6      c     3       111
    7      d     0       111
    8      d     1       111
    9      e     2       111
    10     f     1       111
    11     f     2       111
    12     f     3       111
    13     g     1       111
    14     g     2       111
```

I want to create a dataframe in which column A repeats 0,1,2,3. But there is something missing in the data. I'm trying to fill in the blanks with 0 by appending row values. Here is my expected result:

```
   index   ID     A       B
    
    0      a     0       111
    1      a     1       111
    2      a     2       111
    3      a     3       0
    4      b     0       0
    5      b     1       0
    6      b     2       0
    7      b     3       111
    8      c     0       111
    9      c     1       0
    10     c     2       111
    11     c     3       111
    12     d     0       111
    13     d     1       111
    14     d     2       0
    15     d     3       0
    16     e     0       0
    17     e     1       0
    18     e     2       111
    19     e     3       0
    20     f     0       0
    21     f     1       111
    22     f     2       111
    23     f     3       111
    24     g     0       0
    25     g     1       111
    26     g     2       111
    27     g     3       0
```

Or you can do something like below. Perhaps it will be easier.

```
  index   ID     A       B
    
    0      a     0       111
    1      a     1       111
    2      a     2       111
    3      0     3       0
    4      0     0       0
    5      0     1       0
    6      0     2       0
    7      b     3       111
    8      c     0       111
    9      0     1       0
    10     c     2       111
    11     c     3       111
    12     d     0       111
    13     d     1       111
    14     0     2       0
    15     0     3       0
    16     0     0       0
    17     0     1       0
    18     e     2       111
    19     0     3       0
    20     0     0       0
    21     f     1       111
    22     f     2       111
    23     f     3       111
    24     0     0       0
    25     g     1       111
    26     g     2       111
    27     0     3       0
```

How can I achieve this?

too difficult. What should I do?. I used `.diff().le(0)` when changing from a large number to a small number, such as changing from ID(b) to ID(c). However, when changing from a small number to a large number, such as changing from ID(a) to ID(b) or ID(d) to ID(e), it could not be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pandas reindex function to add rows where there are missing data in column A

try this:

1.

```
gr = df.groupby('ID')


def handle(sub):
    reidx = sub.set_index('A').reindex(range(4))\
        .reset_index().iloc[:, [1, 0, 2]]
    res = reidx.assign(
        ID=reidx.ID.ffill().bfill(),
        B=reidx.B.fillna(0))
    return res


gr.apply(handle).reset_index(drop=True)
>>>
   ID   A   B
0   a   0   111.0
1   a   1   111.0
2   a   2   111.0
3   a   3   0.0
4   b   0   0.0
5   b   1   0.0
6   b   2   0.0
7   b   3   111.0
8   c   0   111.0
9   c   1   0.0
10  c   2   111.0
11  c   3   111.0
12  d   0   111.0
13  d   1   111.0
14  d   2   0.0
15  d   3   0.0
16  e   0   0.0
17  e   1   0.0
18  e   2   111.0
19  e   3   0.0
20  f   0   0.0
21  f   1   111.0
22  f   2   111.0
23  f   3   111.0
24  g   0   0.0
25  g   1   111.0
26  g   2   111.0
27  g   3   0.0
```

2. 

```
gr = df.groupby('ID')


def handle(sub):
    reidx = sub.set_index('A').reindex(range(4))\
        .reset_index().iloc[:, [1, 0, 2]].fillna(0)
    return reidx


gr.apply(handle).reset_index(drop=True)
>>>
    D   A   B
0   a   0   111.0
1   a   1   111.0
2   a   2   111.0
3   0   3   0.0
4   0   0   0.0
5   0   1   0.0
6   0   2   0.0
7   b   3   111.0
8   c   0   111.0
9   0   1   0.0
10  c   2   111.0
11  c   3   111.0
12  d   0   111.0
13  d   1   111.0
14  0   2   0.0
15  0   3   0.0
16  0   0   0.0
17  0   1   0.0
18  e   2   111.0
19  0   3   0.0
20  0   0   0.0
21  f   1   111.0
22  f   2   111.0
23  f   3   111.0
24  0   0   0.0
25  g   1   111.0
26  g   2   111.0
27  0   3   0.0
```

or you can try this:

```
df.set_index(['ID', 'A']).unstack().stack(dropna=False).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer.
But I gave a very simple example.
I'll give you a detailed explanation.
1. There are actually tens of millions of IDs. (Not only from a to g)
2. Column A contains 0~63, not 0~3.
What should I do in this case?

Comment: You only need to change range(4) to range(64)

Comment: If my code solves your problem, can you mark it as an answer

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to the code you provided.